# Sed inline replace sentence in text file AFTER a match is found

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I'm trying to replace the first instance of a sentence in a text file after a match is found. Please note, the `'` quotes are included in the search.

- I'm searching for **the first instance** of: `'database' => 'localhost'`
- I'm replacing **the first instance** with: `'database' => 'new_database'`
- I want to **only** replace after the string `'REPLACE_AFTER_THIS'`

I currently have the first two bullet points working:

```
sed -i file -e "1s/'database' => 'localhost'/'database' => 'new_database'/;t" -e "1,/'database' => 'localhost'/s//'database' => 'new_database'/" file
```

**Input File**

```
'local config' ... 'data'
    'more data'
    'database' => 'localhost'
    'even more data'
'REPLACE_AFTER_THIS' ... 'data'
    'more data'
    'even more data'
    'database' => 'localhost'
'live config'
    'database' => 'localhost'
```

**Expected Output File** *(same file changed inline)*

```
'local config' ... 'data'
    'more data'
    'database' => 'localhost'
    'even more data'
'REPLACE_AFTER_THIS' ... 'data'
    'more data'
    'even more data'
    'database' => 'new_database'
'live config'
    'database' => 'localhost'
```

The above example demonstrates how there is no expected data format *except* for the string `'database' => 'localhost'`, the first occurrence of which needs to change after `'REPLACE_AFTER_THIS'`.

However, I can't figure out how to only do the above *after* finding a certain string. I have tried using grep and a pattern to retrieve all text after `REPLACE_AFTER_THIS`, but then piping into sed instead of using the `-i` flag doesn't perform any changes to the file any more.

How can I alter my currently working solution to incorporate a replacement of the first instance of a sentence after a given string is found in a file?

Comment: Show sample input and your desired output for that sample input.

Comment: @Cyrus it sounds pretty obvious?

Comment: Added an arbitrary example although I'm sure one wasn't need from the bullet points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this with GNU sed:

```
sed -i "/'REPLACE_AFTER_THIS'/,/'database' => 'localhost'/s/'database' => 'localhost'/'database' => 'new_database'/" file
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use awk for this:

```
temp=$(mktemp /tmp/temporary-file.XXXXXXXX)
awk "/REPLACE_AFTER_THIS/{u=1} u && 
 sub(/'database' => 'localhost'/, \"'database' => 'new_database'\") {u=0} 1" file > "$temp"
```

**Output:**

```
'local config' ... 'data'
    'more data'
    'database' => 'localhost'
    'even more data'
'REPLACE_AFTER_THIS' ... 'data'
    'more data'
    'even more data'
    'database' => 'new_database'
'live config'
    'database' => 'localhost'
```

Comment: Hmm, why is `'local config'` there? Please note: *there is no expected data format except for the string `'database' => 'localhost'`* (or is that just your output?).

Comment: It *might* not be there. The **only** guaranteed data in the file will be: `REPLACE_AFTER_THIS` and `'database' => 'localhost'`.

Comment: Ah, that's why I asked "(or is that just your output?)", that makes much more sense, I'll give it a try :-)

Comment: It doesn't update the file. It prints out the change as expected, but the file needs to be updated with the change. Hence why I was using sed's inline `-i`.

Comment: Unfortunately I have GNU Awk 3.1.8. Having to create a file and then overwrite it isn't great if the script doesn't have access to the directory, only the file, and I don't want to used `setfacl` for extra permissions to the directory to get it working :-(

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I chose the sed solution instead :-) +1 for your effort, though